# Force R to always round up to two decimal places

Tags: r, rounding

I am looking for a solution but could not find a solution yet.
Really basic, i want R to always round up my numbers until two decimal places so

2,3421 should be rounded to 2,35

```
a <- 2.3423
format(round(a,digits=2),nsmall=2)
```

still gives
`2.34`
I am new to R and related topics always seemed to be a little different.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your numbers are in a numeric vector :

```
format(round(a,digits=2),nsmall=2)
```

which gives a character vector. The `format` function is there so that 1 is displayed as `1.00` and not `1` for example. If you don't care about that, omit it.

---

If you want 2.3421 to be rounded to 2.35 (not standard rounding but ceiling at 2 decimals), use

```
format(ceiling(a*100)/100,nsmall=2)
```

or more legible with pipes:

```
a %>% multiply_by(100) %>% ceiling %>% divide_by(100) %>% format(2)
```

Without format: `ceiling(a*100)/100` which gives you a numeric.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I updated my code above with your answer but your code does not seem to do what i want.

Comment: I added an edit with ceiling